# Generating Invoices C# WinForms

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I have this application:

1. A form with TextBoxes like Company name where user inputs company name and so on.
2. TextBox for Product user to enter price quantity.
3. And a button which leads to the report Viewer( I already designed the invoice look alike) and have datasets in tables to display data

That's all on the form.

Now the report viewer appears and the user prints or choosing to save as Excel or Pdf- Ok, it's great.

Now user exists the form with report viewer and I want to keep history of the invoices (of the reports).

I designed this form and I managed to create A rdlc. Report and display it in report viewer. But how do i reload this reports( Example: i have a dataGridView Listing all invoices if user clicks a row in dataGridView Report Viewer should open with that invoice) how to do that? Im not referring to save it as Excel or PDF just Keeping History of this Invoices.

So I want history of all the invoices created with the report viewer.How to do that? To be able to reopen whenever I want (not saving to Excel or pdf) Open in reportViewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do that in database. You can create an InvoiceHistory table and whenever user generates the invoice save it to the history table. Then when you want to display all invoices use the history table to display and clicking on any invoice will use the history data to generate the report in reportviewer. There is no way to store history in reportviewer. As the reportviewer name says its just a viewer of the rdlc report what changes is the data so you need to keep a history of data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and interest nice explanation, So let me see. I have to create table of HistoryInvoices and Whenever the user Press the button to view the report i should insert into database all details ?(Customer Company,Prices,Products) and when displaying in DataGridView this HistoryInvoices Table from Sql Server. And user clicks i should load data from Database where that record is In the Report wich is displayed in ReportViewer?

Comment: Yes if you want to keep a history of invoices whenever user clicks the button.

Comment: You might want to name the table InvoiceGenerationHistory as its a history of invoice generation. Store only the data you will need.

Comment: I will mark as right answer, But can you explain me in a few words how to configure the .rdlc so that takes the Data from database ? I need TextBoxes with Datasets in it ? or Table's (Tablix)  setting it to Certain datasets from data table

Comment: You can find out how to do that by going to below Url. It uses DataTable but you can use Objects to bind to the report too.  http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/RDLC-Local-SSRS-Report-ASPNet-Example-using-DataSet-or-DataTable-in-C-VBNet-and-Visual-Studio-2010.aspx